# Rails Savon HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, httpclient, keep-alive, savon

it's my first time posting on stack overflow, so here it goes...
I'm having an issue when I try to make an api call using rails, but I keep getting a `HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected` error. Since I am new to Ruby and rails, I don't know where to start looking.

Here is my source...

```
site_ids = { 'int' => (An integer) }
source_credentials = { 'SourceName' => '(username)', 'Password' => '(password)', 'SiteIDs' => site_ids }
user_credentials = { 'Username' => '(another username)', 'Password' => '(another password)', 'SiteIDs' => site_ids }

#######################
## Standard API call ##
#######################

#Create Savon client using default settings
http_client = Savon.client(wsdl: "(Valid WSDL location)")

#Create request and package it for the call
http_request = { 'SourceCredentials' => source_credentials, 'UserCredentials' => user_credentials  }
params = { 'Request' => http_request }

#Run the call and store the results
result = http_client.call(:get_staff, params)
```

After attempting to run this, I get the following error:

`HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected`
on the line that uses `http_request.call`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of httpclient are you using?

Comment: The version of httpclient that I am using is 2.3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

Solution for my situation: my resource worked via https, but when i receive data with wsdl - server response with http endpoint. As a result - savon made soap request via http.

```
req = client.build_request(:action, message: data)
req.url
req.ssl?
```

In this case you can just specify endpoint for savon

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: YOUR_URL_WITH_WSDL, endpoint: YOUR_URL) # wsdl
```